# Prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $(\Bbb{Z},+)$ if and only if $\exists!n \in \Bbb{N}$, so that $H=n\Bbb{Z} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How to prove that if:

$H$ is a subgroup  of  $(\Bbb{Z},+)$ if and only if $\exists!n \in \Bbb{N}$, so that  $H=n\Bbb{Z} $

Intuitively I understand the implications, can you please help me prove them more rigorous.

Thank you.

Comment: Division with remainder. Take the smallest nonnegative number in $H$. This is the modulus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $H=\{0\}$, then $H=0\mathbb Z$.

Otherwise, there is some $n\in H\setminus\{0\}$. Then $n>0$ or $n<0$. If $n<0$, then $-n\in H$ and $-n>0$. So, you know that there is some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $n\in H$. Let $N$ be the smallest among such elements. If $h\in H$, then $h=Nq+r$, with $r\in\{0,1,\ldots,N-1\}$. Then $r=h-Nq\in H$. But $r<N$. Therefore, $r=0$. So, $H=N\mathbb Z$.

On the other hand, it is clear than, for each natural $n$, $n\mathbb Z$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$.